# Is there any solutions available to send data from BluetoothGattServer to connected devices simultaneously?

Tags: bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, bluetooth-gatt, android-ble

Here is my server code:

`private BluetoothGattServer mGattServer;`

```
mBluetoothLeAdvertiser = mBluetoothAdapter.getBluetoothLeAdvertiser();
GattServerCallback gattServerCallback = new GattServerCallback(this, context.getApplicationContext());
mGattServer = mBluetoothManager.openGattServer(context, gattServerCallback);

        BluetoothGattService service = new BluetoothGattService(SERVICE_UUID,
                BluetoothGattService.SERVICE_TYPE_PRIMARY);

        // Write characteristic
        BluetoothGattCharacteristic writeCharacteristic = new BluetoothGattCharacteristic(
                CHARACTERISTIC_ECHO_UUID,
                BluetoothGattCharacteristic.PROPERTY_WRITE | BluetoothGattCharacteristic.PROPERTY_READ | BluetoothGattCharacteristic.PROPERTY_WRITE_NO_RESPONSE,
                // Somehow this is not necessary, the client can still enable notifications//
                BluetoothGattCharacteristic.PERMISSION_WRITE | BluetoothGattDescriptor.PERMISSION_READ);


        BluetoothGattDescriptor clientConfigurationDescriptor = new BluetoothGattDescriptor(
                CHARACTERISTIC_AUDIO_UUID,
                BluetoothGattDescriptor.PERMISSION_READ | BluetoothGattDescriptor.PERMISSION_WRITE);
        clientConfigurationDescriptor.setValue(BluetoothGattDescriptor.ENABLE_NOTIFICATION_VALUE);

        service.addCharacteristic(writeCharacteristic);
        mGattServer.addService(service);
```

Once a client is connected, I am adding the connected device to my device list:

```
@Override    
public void onConnectionStateChange(BluetoothDevice device, int status, int newState) {
        super.onConnectionStateChange(device, status, newState);
        mServerActionListener.log("onConnectionStateChange " + device.getAddress()
                + "\nstatus " + status
                + "\nnewState " + newState);

        if (newState == BluetoothProfile.STATE_CONNECTED) {
            mServerActionListener.addDevice(device);
            //mServerActionListener.notifyCharacteristicEcho("start".getBytes());
        } else if (newState == BluetoothProfile.STATE_DISCONNECTED) {
            mServerActionListener.removeDevice(device);
        }
    }
```

Here I am sending data:

```
 BluetoothGattService service = mGattServer.getService(SERVICE_UUID);
        BluetoothGattCharacteristic characteristic = service.getCharacteristic(uuid);
        characteristic.setValue(value);
        // Indications require confirmation, notifications do not
        boolean confirm = BluetoothUtils.requiresConfirmation(characteristic);

        for (BluetoothDevice device : mDevices) {
            mGattServer.notifyCharacteristicChanged(device, characteristic, confirm);
        }
```

Right now I am sending data to multiple connected devices by iterating through the devices list. But we cannot notify lengthy data like streaming through this way. Because when multiple notifications are to be sent, an application must wait for onNotificationSent callback to be received before sending additional notifications.

Is there any other solutions available to send data to the connected devices? I want to send notification to all connected devices at the same time.


In ios it is possible to send data to the list of devices. 'chunk' is the list of devices in the below code.

```
peripheralManager.updateValue(chunk, for: transCharacteristic, onSubscribedCentrals: arrCentral)
```